# Tor list of US bridges

Tags: bridge

Is there a list of US (United States) only bridges for tor? I need to relay thru US bridges only.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no such list and it is not possible to get such a list. The idea of bridges is that they are hidden. So you won't find a public list of all bridges or only a greater subset of all bridges.

In general you can use any bridge from any country. Just go to [bridges.torproject.org](https://bridges.torproject.org/bridges?transport=obfs4), solve the CAPTCHA and receive your bridges. Or go to [about:preferences#tor](http://about:preferences#tor) in Tor Browser and select a bridge.